# Powershell - Delete Registry Key - Wildcard in RegPath

Tags: powershell, registry, wildcard

I want to delete the following registry key:

```
$regpath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Adobe*"
```

The problem is that I have to use a wildcard. So I cannot use:

```
Remove-Item -Path $regpath
```

And I cannot use Remove-ItemProperty as "Adobe*" is a subkey and not a value.

Do you have any ideas?

THANKS in advance!

Comment: Why can you not use `Remove-Item -Path $regpath`? What happens when you do?

Comment: It does not delete the key

Comment: Curious, I'm not able to reproduce this at all. Wildcard path `Adobe*` should expand to include any key literally named `Adobe*` as well, but try `Remove-Item -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Adobe*'` (`-LiteralPath` = no wildcard globbing)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either. On both _Windows Powershell 5.1_ and _Powershell 7.2.0_, the `*` wildcard used in `Remove-Item -Path` removes registry keys as expected.

Are you getting any message? Maybe try with `-Verbose` or `-Debug`?